# Query a pure join table created in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first, join

I've created a pure join table out of the folowing two tables:

User:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int UserID { get; set; }
public string UserName { get; set; }
public String FirstName { get; set; }
public String LastName { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<CrRole> Roles { get; set; }
```

Role:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int RoleID { get; set; }
public String RoleName { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<CrUser> Users { get; set; }
```

Fluent API to create the UserRole join Table:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<CrUser>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Roles)
        .WithMany(i => i.Users)
        .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("UserID")
            .MapRightKey("RoleID")
            .ToTable("CrUserRole"));
```

This works fine, and creates the correct CrUserRole table with UserID and RoleID columns.

I am having great difficulty in trying to work out how to do a simple query against this join table though. In SQL the command would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM UserRole ur
WHERE ur.RoleID = @RoleID
AND   ur.UserID = @UserID
```

I've tried going through the navigation links of either the Role or User entities, but always seem to end up with a load of spaghetti code which refuses to compile :-(

I'd be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction. Even some tutorials would help, the ones I've found only seem to only go as far as creating the join table and not include CRUD operations.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kaymar.

The version I eventually used was:

```
String[] returnUsers = new String[1]; 

var role = context.Roles.First(r=>r.RoleName.Equals(roleName)); 

returnUsers = role.Users.Select(s => s.UserName).ToArray();
```

Thanks for getting me in the right direction, and apologies for taking months to update this!

Answer (score 2):

notice your mapping:

```
 t.MapLeftKey("UserID")
.MapRightKey("RoleID")
.ToTable("CrUserRole"));
```

this mapping shows that your query's result will always be 1 or 0.
The proper way to do this IMO is as follows:
You have both user id and role id right?
First get the user, then query that specific user's roles. Something like:

```
var user = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserID == myUserId);
var role = user.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.RoleId = myRoleId);
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamyar, that compiles at least! Will try it out once I've got some tests together for it. Thanks :-)